# How should I transform T | T[] to T[] in typescript?

Tags: typescript

I am attempting to transform an input of type `T | T[]` into an output of `T[]`. That is, if  `input` is an array of T, simply return it. Otherwise, return `[input]`.

What is the best type-safe way to go about this in Typescript?

Comment: Be aware that any code for this won’t wort correctly if T itself is an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function arrayify( something: T | readonly T[] ): T[] {
    return Array.isArray( something ) ? something : [ something ];
}
```